# Присвоение значений ComboBox!

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужна помощь! Как присвоить значение комбобокс? Я новичок в C#! Нужно присвоить значение Type/brand/model/benchmark к Combobox, можно по отдельности, можно вместе. (Еще нужна помощь в коде, WriteLine я уберу сам)) по-сути все) (Сразу извиняюсь за криво-вставленный код, я не знаю как его правильно тут вставить (новичок на сайте, в т.ч.)

```csharp
namespace combobox_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //vse processori
        class CPUs
        {
            void Test(string[] args)
            {
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\denchicka\Desktop\ДИПЛОМ\CPU_UserBenchmarks.csv"))
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    {
                        var records = new List<CPU>();
                        csv.Read();
                        csv.ReadHeader();
                        while (csv.Read())
                        {
                            var record = new CPU
                            {
                                Type = csv.GetField<string>("Type"),
                                Brand = csv.GetField<string>("Brand"),
                                Model = csv.GetField<string>("Model"),
                                Benchmark = csv.GetField<float>("Benchmark")

                            };
                            records.Add(record);
                        }

                        foreach (var record in records)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(record.Type + " " + record.Brand + " " + record.Model + " " + record.Benchmark);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //CPU
            class CPU
            {
                public string Type { get; set; }
                public string Brand { get; set; }
                public string Model { get; set; }
                public float Benchmark { get; set; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не используте вложенные классы. Чтобы выполнить код при загрузке программы, создайте в дизайнере формы обработчик события `Form.Load`. Вызывайте метод загрузки из него.

[image: Form.Load]

Положите файл с данными в каталог с запускаемой программой, чтобы при ее перемещении, в другую папку она не поломалась. `Application.StartupPath` - способ получить путь к каталогу запуска приложения.

Код получится примерно такой.

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CPU> cpus = CPUs.GetCPUValues();
        foreach (CPU cpu in cpus)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(cpu.Type + " " + cpu.Brand + " " + cpu.Model + " " + cpu.Benchmark);
        }
    }
}

public static class CPUs
{
    public static List<CPU> GetCPUValues()
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "CPU_UserBenchmarks.csv");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var records = new List<CPU>();
            csv.Read();
            csv.ReadHeader();
            while (csv.Read())
            {
                var record = new CPU
                {
                    Type = csv.GetField<string>("Type"),
                    Brand = csv.GetField<string>("Brand"),
                    Model = csv.GetField<string>("Model"),
                    Benchmark = csv.GetField<float>("Benchmark")

                };
                records.Add(record);
            }
            return records;
        }
    }
}

public class CPU
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public float Benchmark { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Не получается, выдает ошибку .GetCPUValues = такого вроде вообще нет, там 4 значения, Enumerator, hashcode, range, type

Comment: @0day. Вы внимательно скопировали мой код? Модификатор `static` у класса заметили?

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все получилось. Не подскажите, где мне начать обучение лучше?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, чтобы нормально получалось кодить, откуда вообще начинать?

Comment: @0day. можно [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ)

Comment: Так-с, хорошо, спасибо. Если возникнут еще проблемы я могу как-то с Вами связаться? Просто я делаю тут дипломный проект и хотелось бы знать, к кому обращаться, в случае чего... ;)

Comment: @0day. "Спасение утопающих - дело рук самих утопающих" (с). :) А я всего-лишь случайный прохожий. Успехов!